# Extracting specific parts of a value from an array index

Tags: php, arrays

I have the current code

```
$trace = exec("tracert 192.168.0.1", $outcome, $status);

print_r($outcome);
```

which is outputting an array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => Tracing route to 192.168.0.1 over a maximum of 30 hops [2] => [3] => 1 <1 ms <1 ms <1 ms 192.168.1.1 [4] => 2 5 ms 4 ms 4 ms 192.168.0.1 [5] => [6] => Trace complete. )
```

Now what I specifically want to get at is the latency values (ms) in elements 3 and 4. I can get these using print_r($outcome[3]) for example which outputs:

```
1 <1 ms <1 ms <1 ms 192.168.1.1
```

However all I want from this is the '`<1ms <1ms <1ms`' bit.

What would be the best way to get just this? Bearing in mind that this is just an example and these values are subject to change.

Would appreciate any advice or input! Thanks :)

Comment: _these values are subject to change_ - will it keep the same pattern though? will it always be element 3?  And I think you mean `echo $outcome[3];` not `print_r`

Comment: It would be better if you could specify exactly the output format you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
<?[0-9]+ ?ms
```

Confirmed [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%3C?%5B0-9%5D%2b%20?ms&input=1%20%3C1%20ms%20%3C1%20ms%20%3C1%20ms%20192.168.1.1).

Comment: This worked although I needed to add a forward slash like so: /<?[0-9]+ ?ms/ - to get it working with preg_match. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to tweak this, but here's a start:

Also, this works on the raw output, not an array. I would change `exec()` to `system()` and capture the output using an output buffer. Or, you could modify the code and use `preg_match` on each line of the array from exec.

```
preg_match_all('/(<?[0-9]+ ms <?[0-9]+ ms <?[0-9]+ ms)/i', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `strrpos` allows you to find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string. So if you know it'll always output 'ms' as the last occurence, you can use:

```
$last_occurrence = strrpos($outcome[3], ' ms');
```

To return the first (however many) characters of the string:

```
$adjusted_string = substr($outcome[3], 0, $last_occurrence);
```

**EDIT:**

And to get rid of the first character:

```
echo substr($adjusted_string, 1);
```

So if you want to group it all together:

```
echo substr(substr($outcome[3], 0, strrpos($outcome[3], ' ms')), 1);
```

Comment: This would still include the first number value the leads the latency values the OP is looking for (`1` in his example)

Answer (score 0):

If it keeps the same pattern you can do

```
list(,$l1,$lu1,$l2,$lu2,$l3,$lu3,) = explode(" ", $outcome[3]);
echo $l1.$lu1.' '.$l2.$lu2.' '.$l3.$lu3;
```

see it here: http://codepad.org/RwfeGusi

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
// create array to store the results
$result = array();

// loop through all lines of the outcome
foreach ($outcome as $line)
{
    // continue to the next line if there is no "ms" information in the line
    if (strpos($line, 'ms') === FALSE)
    {
        continue;
    }

    // remove the initial number (counter) from the line
    $line = ltrim($line, '0123456789');

    // split the string in pieces
    $latency_values = explode(' ms ', $line);

    // throw away the latest element (IP address)
    array_pop($latency_values);

    // remove surrounding white spaces
    $latency_values = array_map('trim', $latency_values);

    // add to our result array
    $result[] = $latency_values;
}

// output the result
print_r($result);
```

This solution uses:

- [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) loop
- [strpos](http://php.net/strpos)
- [ltrim](http://php.net/ltrim)
- [explode](http://php.net/explode)
- [array_pop](http://php.net/array_pop)
- [array_map](http://php.net/array_map)
- [trim](http://php.net/trim)

Comment: @Bernard: if you want `<1ms <1ms <1ms` format, just change the line after "add to our result array" to: `$result[] = implode('ms ', $latency_values);`